# Battery management system for 3.7v

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion

For my project i want to connect 109 Li-ion cell in parallel then the battery pack of capacity increased to 3.7v 272.5Ah and convert by boost converter into 48V supply to motor. how to protect those cells.How to construct battery management system for my cause?.if there is any solution please guide to construct it or any product is available in market?

Comment: Please edit your title, ALL CAPS is not appreciated...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The safety problem is that if any cell goes short circuit, the other parallel cells could drive a very large current through it. You therefore require a fuse in series with each cell.

The practicality problem is that with 1s109p, you have a very low voltage high current battery. A boost converter from 3v to 48v will not have the highest efficiency, and you will need very thick cables from the battery to the converter. It would be far better to have a higher voltage, lower capacity battery, say 8s13p, or 6s18p. You will get better efficiency from a smaller ratio boost converter, and require much smaller cables from the battery to the converter.